# Get all points with a specific distance, which are on a road

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

is it possible with the google maps api to get all points with a specific distance, which are on a road?

I try to explain:

E.g. I need all the points, which are 5km away from a start point and which are hit/lie on a road.

Like this image: (black points)

[points on road](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CntN1.png)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. You will have a better chance at getting an answer if you show what you've already tried. Check [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @user2314737 Yeah you're right. But I haven't any idea, to solve my problem. I can draw a circle with google maps api, i can check if a point is on the circle, but i haven't any idea to check, if the point is on a road/way.

Comment: Which technologies are you using? JS? Android? IOS? ..?

Comment: @AndreaM16 sorry, it's Javascript. But i'm not bonded. It's an web application.

Comment: @TheRarios BD System? Backe-end tech?

Answer (score 0):

**In Javascript:**
For checking if a point is on a road you can use [`DirectionsService`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)  the method `ComputeDistance` from the location to itself and then the[`google.maps.geometry.spherical`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) library to compute the distance from the starting point and end point of the first leg of the computed route.

```
// DIRECTIONS service
var dist2road = 0;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var request = {
  origin: latLng,
  destination: latLng,
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
};

// compute distance to nearest road dist2road 
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    dist2road = Math.round(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location,e.latLng),2);
  }
```

If the distance lies below a given threshold, you can say that the point is on a road.

Here's a [demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical)